# Forward declaration of a template class c++

Tags: c++

I saw similar examples, but didn't understand them fully so please don't mark this as duplicate straight away.
I think there's a simple solution for my problem, and I'm only learning `C++`.

I want to use:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class arnas_array {
//a copy of std:array functionality, basically, here.
};
```

in another class header, another file, example:

```
class options_databaze {

public:

    struct options_to_save{
        arnas_array<char, 123> option_name;
        //char option_name[103];
        int * option_value_pointer; 
    };


};
```

And I can't get it to work.
Forward declaration like this won't work:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class arnas_array;
```

I don't know much about this problem, first time I'm stuck here, any examples are gold.

```
error C2079: 'options_databaze::options_to_save::option_name' uses undefined class 'arnas_array<char,123>'
```

Comment: Your forward declaration is actually perfectly fine, however you cannot use a forward declared class to declare a member of that type until the class is fully defined (because otherwise the compiler would have no way of determining the size of the member and thus the size of `struct options_to_save`). You can declare a member that's a pointer to that type, however (data pointers are all the same size regardless of their type). (And you're missing a `;` at the end of your class definition, but I'm sure that's just a copy-paste error.)

Comment: how should i avoid forward declarations then and use same class in every file ? i wouldnt like to change my code to use pointers, im editing application, not writing new code in this situation

Comment: As a tip, always include the actual error messages you get when trying to compile the code when posting

Comment: error C2079: 'options_databaze::options_to_save::option_name' uses undefined class 'arnas_array<char,123>'

Comment: @Arnas: You can put the definition of `arnas_array` in a header (I'm assuming that's already the case since it's templated) and include that header before you define `options_databaze`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with templates. In C++ a class type `T` must be complete, in particular, if a non-static class data member of type `T` is declared (see `3.2/5 (One definition rule)` section of the standard, or read [more human-readable version here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)).

"Must be complete" means that the definition of the class `T` should precede the definition of the corresponding data member. A common way to achieve this, as was pointed out by Cameron in the comments, is to put a definition in a header file and include that header everywhere it's needed - just the same way as you do when you include standard headers such as `<vector>`, `<map>` and so on.

Comment: thanks, since this class was already in header(which had all the defines, and other 2 small classes, its like a "main" header of thingies) i tought that's not the case, since i had that header included. But seems like seperate header with arnas_array class defined fixed the things.